# Outlook 2010 overriding Windows 7 visual theme settings

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, colors, themes

I'm helping a visually impaired friend of mine learn how to use her Windows 8 computer. My friends accesses her computer using the JAWS screenreader (http://www.freedomscientific.com/Products/Blindness/JAWS), but as she has some sight she also has the screen set with a large font size and the "High Contrast Black" theme.

This theme works fine throughout pretty much all of the computer, and displays white text on a black background wherever text would usually displayed as black on a white background. However, in Outlook 2010 emails from some senders appear as white text on a white background.

I've spent some time looking at the problem, and from what I can tell it's caused by some senders sending HTML emails that explicitly set the background colour of the email. Then, rather that Outlook doing the sensible thing and letting the Windows theme override any colour settings, it lets the HTML in the email set the background colour. Even more crazy, Outlook then takes the text colour from the Windows theme: so, the emails are displayed as white text on a white background!

Here's a stripped back example of the HTML in one of the offending emails:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <style type="text/css" style="display:none;"><!-- P {margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;} --></style>
  </head>
  <body dir="ltr">
    <div id="divtagdefaultwrapper" style="font-size:12pt;color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Calibri,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;">
      <p class="western" align="center" style="margin-bottom: 0cm; line-height: 100%"><font style="font-size: 12pt"><b>Here's where the text of the email would go.</b></font></p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

It seems to me that the "background-color:#ffffff" in the  tag is what's causing the problem. How can I go about fixing this? I've asked in another questions about getting senders to send plain text emails, but as the problem affects so many senders that really isn't a practical way forward. It's very frustrating, especially as I'm using two Microsoft products and they aren't working properly together.

Comment: You would need to fix `background-color:#FFFFFF` as well. In fact swap the two around. You may be able to do this with some VBA but that's outside of my knowledge :/

Comment: Yes, you're quite right, I've corrected my question. Thank you for the VBA question, I'll check that out!